# Memory, performance issues 8gb system

Tags: chromium, memory-usage

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 on a 8gb ram, 8gb swap, intel i7-2600 CPU @ 3.40GHz x 4, 64 bit

Gallium 0.4 on AMD CAICOS (DRM 2.43.0 / 4.4.0-98-generic, LLVM 4.0.0)

The system used to perform just fine, but it is lagging badly, I think due to lack of memory/swap.  By lagging I mean going in and out of grey screens, mouse, keyboard become unresponsive.

[image]

I installed mint on a laptop with similar resources recently, and really noticed the lack of lag. . . making it more annoying than ever to work on the desktop listed above.

I have been running System Monitor for the past week or two.  When the system lags, memory is maxed out >95%.  A bad script in chromium will bring this computer to its knees for five minutes until it is purged.

Chromium or Firefox are consistently the memory offenders. At the moment I have 6 tabs open in Chromium and it's eating more than 3.4gb ram.

So... I don't have enough memory.  Before I try to increase swap size or cannibalize a windows partition, can I improve software performance (or limit its' ability to consume RAM), are there system changes that could be made, or do I just need to get another 8gb of ram?  (Seems like 8 should have been ample).

`free` output:
[image]

Updated screenshot of resource issues:
[image: updated screenshot of resource issues]

Comment: 8 GB of RAM is usually decent these days for normal desktop usage. Please add the output of `free` (press Ctrl+Alt+T to open a terminal) to your question.

Comment: Can't see anything abnormal from the system monitor screenshot.  Note that Chromium will see that you have tons of memory and will use up a lot, so nothing unusual there - it would use less if you have less.  The description of mouse and keyboard becoming unresponsive implies that it's not due to lack of memory or swapping

Comment: So, I updated the screen shots for when the issue is actually happening.  Free output also.

Comment: Strange... I currently have 12 tabs open and firefox is using less than 500mb of ram.

Answer (score 2):

Firefox pre-quantum would bring my system to a crawl.  This was remedied recently with FF-quantum.  If this remedies the issue, feedback is appreciated.   My Ubuntu laptop is a 1.7 Ghz quad-core with the maximum of a 8GB RAM and is now very usable with the FF upgrade.  Ring the bell by up-voting this post if you have installed FFQ and the performance is now reasonable or better.

Comment: That's why I quit using foxfire and switched to chromium as it was billed as a lighter weight.  So the tables have turned and the newest foxfire update corrects FF's notorious memory handling problems?

Comment: [As I understand it, FFQ leverages multi-core CPUs to render pages quickly. ][1].   Significant improvement


  [1]: https://www.digitaltrends.com/web/firefox-quantum-hands-on-review/